# Is there a convention for making text as an index in math

Tags: math-mode, superscripts

Taking an example from category theory, given a category "C", the opposite category is usually denoted "C^op". Where "op" is an abbreviation for opposite.
Now there are three ways to put this in latex:

- As `C^{op}`
- As `C^\operatorname{op}`
- As `C^\text{op}`

While I wouldn't use the first one, thw second and third both make sense to me in some way. So is their a convention which one should use, and if so, what's the reasoning behind it

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The first one might not be a good idea, like you already noticed, because *`op`* could be mistaken for *`o⋅p`*. But I don’t think the other options are correct either.

`\operatorname{op}` puts correct spacing around keywords, when used as mathematical operators. That is not the case here.

`\text{op}`, at least syntactical, means prose. But you are trying to display mathematical notation.

So I think the best way is to use `\mathrm{op}`. Or still better, define

```
\newcommand\opcat[1]{{#1}^{\mathrm{op}}
```

and use it as `\opcat{C}`.

Comment: 7 seconds slower (but we agree on the answer:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: Indeed, congratulations, you have my upvote ;-)

Comment: Likewise, you have mine:-)

Comment: I would argue for the use of \text, due to its font-preserving properties, and the fact that the label (not an index) is actually text. You're not merely marking up some mathematical symbols in a Roman font, you're indicating the presence of a standard vernacular word or abbreviation thereof.

Comment: @Xerxes I'd strongly disagree here `op` is not an abbreviation for a natural language vernacular word; it is a specific categorical operator which just happens to use a superscript rather than prefix notation. It should not pick up the surrounding text font any more than `log` or `sin` should.

Comment: Perhaps I'm missing something. Are these not abbreviations for "opposite", "logarithm" and "sine", respectively? That's what the original question indicated.

Answer (score 15):

Definitely not `^{op}` the math italic font should never be used for multi-letter identifiers.

`^\operatorname{op}` (by default) uses the same font as `\mathrm` with `\mathop` spacing (the same as `\log` or `\sin`. The `\mathop` has no effect in the usage shown but would in other contexts.

`^\text{op}` (with the amsmath definition of `\text`) will make a mathord, using the current *text* font.

Probably I would use (a macro defined as) `\mathrm{op}` so that it uses the `\mathrm` font with mathord spacing.